# Spark (OneHotEncoder + StringIndexer) = FeatureImportance how to?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

When I do the data prep for my matrix with StringIndexer and OneHot Encoder, How can I now what are the name/origin of the important features ?

A randomForest classifier will only give me indices, and I don't see the link with original data :-(

Following code from here : 
https://github.com/spark-in-action/first-edition/blob/master/ch08/python/ch08-listings.py

on this dataset : 
https://github.com/spark-in-action/first-edition/blob/master/ch08/adult.names

I extracted this subset of code :

```
$data.take(1)
[Row(age=39.0, occupation=u' State-gov', capital_gain=77516.0, education=u' Bachelors', marital_status=u' Never-married', workclass=u' Adm-clerical', relationship=u' Not-in-family', race=u' White', sex=u' Male', capital_loss=2174.0, fnlwgt=0.0, hours_per_week=40.0, native_country=u' United-States', income=u' <=50K')]

$data2 = indexStringColumns(data, typeString)
$data2.take(1)
>[Row(age=39.0, capital_gain=77516.0, capital_loss=2174.0, fnlwgt=0.0, hours_per_week=40.0, occupation=4.0, education=2.0, marital_status=1.0, workclass=3.0, relationship=1.0, race=0.0, sex=0.0, native_country=0.0, income=0.0)]

$data3 = oneHotEncodeColumns(data2, colString_without_Y)
$data3.take(1)
>[Row(age=39.0, capital_gain=77516.0, capital_loss=2174.0, fnlwgt=0.0, hours_per_week=40.0, income=0.0, occupation=SparseVector(9, {4: 1.0}), education=SparseVector(16, {2: 1.0}), marital_status=SparseVector(7, {1: 1.0}), workclass=SparseVector(15, {3: 1.0}), relationship=SparseVector(6, {1: 1.0}), race=SparseVector(5, {0: 1.0}), sex=SparseVector(2, {0: 1.0}), native_country=SparseVector(42, {0: 1.0}))]

$# modélisation :

$rf          = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol=colY, numTrees=ntree, maxDepth=depth,)
$model       = rf.fit(trainingData)
$predictions = model.transform(testData)

$model.featureImportances
>SparseVector(107, {0: 0.1016, 1: 0.0302, 2: 0.0995, 3: 0.0207, 4: 0.0517, 5: 0.007, 6: 0.0061, 7: 0.0033, 8: 0.0021, 9: 0.0041, 10: 0.0058, 11: 0.0036, 12: 0.0001, 14: 0.0162, 15: 0.0067, 16: 0.0199, 17: 0.0134, 18: 0.0026, 19: 0.0059, 20: 0.0025, 21: 0.0038, 22: 0.0053, 23: 0.0064, 24: 0.003, 25: 0.0014, 26: 0.007, 27: 0.0023, 28: 0.001, 29: 0.0002, 30: 0.1473, 31: 0.0609, 32: 0.0057, 33: 0.0024, 34: 0.0019, 35: 0.001, 36: 0.0002, 37: 0.0258, 38: 0.0054, 39: 0.0244, 40: 0.0045, 41: 0.0055, 42: 0.0186, 43: 0.0061, 44: 0.0021, 45: 0.0043, 46: 0.0029, 47: 0.0046, 48: 0.0024, 49: 0.0019, 50: 0.0001, 51: 0.0, 52: 0.0786, 53: 0.0354, 54: 0.0169, 55: 0.0117, 56: 0.015, 57: 0.0026, 58: 0.0046, 59: 0.0064, 60: 0.0025, 61: 0.0014, 62: 0.0011, 63: 0.007, 64: 0.0312, 65: 0.0048, 66: 0.005, 67: 0.0022, 68: 0.0008, 69: 0.0008, 70: 0.0006, 71: 0.0006, 72: 0.0003, 73: 0.0013, 74: 0.0006, 75: 0.0012, 76: 0.0004, 77: 0.0003, 78: 0.0002, 79: 0.0005, 80: 0.0002, 81: 0.0003, 82: 0.0002, 83: 0.0003, 84: 0.0004, 85: 0.0002, 86: 0.0001, 87: 0.0003, 88: 0.0004, 89: 0.0001, 90: 0.0, 91: 0.0005, 93: 0.0004, 94: 0.0002, 95: 0.0003, 96: 0.0, 97: 0.0001, 98: 0.0001, 99: 0.0001, 100: 0.0, 101: 0.0, 102: 0.0, 103: 0.0, 104: 0.0, 105: 0.0002})
```

How can I know to what categorial value is each indice linked back to in the original data matrice ??

Answer (score 2):

[`StringIndexerModel.labels`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel.labels) is what you need.

For example,

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

data = sc.parallelize([
  Row(v="A"),
  Row(v="B"), 
]).toDF()

labels = StringIndexer(inputCol="v", outputCol="indexed").fit(data).labels

for idx, v in enumerate(labels):
  print idx, v
```

`OneHotEncoder` isn't much of an issue here since it just converts a number to an index. Note that

> The last category is not included by default (configurable via dropLast)

So you need to make sure the value & indices are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to map the labels that I get from StringIndexer to the feature importance of model. The labels will be mapped in the end.
The below example is in scala, but the approach will be the same.

Create DataFrame:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "a",0),
  (1, "b",1),
  (2, "c",0),
  (3, "a",0),
  (4, "a",1),
 (5, "c",1)
)).toDF("id", "category","y")
```

Encode category to a column of category indices and get labels

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer}
val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("category").setOutputCol("categoryIndex").fit(df)
val indexed = indexer.transform(df)
val labels = indexer.labels.map("Category=" + _)
```

This is how `labels` look

```
scala> labels
res9: Array[String] = Array(Category=a, Category=c, Category=b)
```

Map category indices to binary vectors using OneHotEncoder

```
val encoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("categoryIndex").setOutputCol("categoryVec")
val encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
encoded.select("id", "categoryVec").show()
```

Train RandomForest model

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{RandomForestClassificationModel, RandomForestClassifier}
val rf = new RandomForestClassifier().setLabelCol("y").setFeaturesCol("categoryVec").setNumTrees(10)
val rfmodel = rf.fit(encoded)
```

Now to get feature importance mapped to labels we need to zip featureImportance indices and values, and then in the map we will get label at that index location `labels(x._1)`, where `x._1` is the index value.

```
val featureImportance = rfmodel.featureImportances.toSparse
val topFeatures = featureImportance.indices.zip(featureImportance.values).sortBy( - _._2).map(x => (labels(x._1),x._2))
```

This is how the final output `topFeatures` will look:

```
Array[(String, Double)] = Array((Category=a,0.7998663887552777), (Category=c,0.20013361124472231))
```

Comment: This work for only one encoder, how to do if we encode several columns ?